# Trouble with as.Date

Tags: r, as.date

I currently have date data in the following format: DDMMYYYY

I want to convert the dates to proper date function (I suspect I will need to for visualizing the temporal data) using the following:

```
data$DATE<-as.Date(as.character(data$DATE), "%d%m%Y")
```

which would be fine, however days with single digits cause me to get NA results because there is no 0 infront.

Example:

```
17042018  = 2018-05-10
 5022018  = NA
```

What is a work around? Should I just paste a 0 in instances where characters is less than 8?

I am quite new to R, but if you could send me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Regards,
G

Comment: Please show us some sample data.

Comment: Hi Tim, I copied the first two instances, one which worked and one which didn't. As you can see, the second instance is missing a 0 at the front

Answer (score 1):

Pad the string with zeros till length 8, then convert:

```
a <- '5102017'
a <- sprintf('%08d', as.numeric(a))
as.Date(a, "%d%m%Y")
```

Or, in your example:

```
data$DATE <- as.Date(sprintf('%08d', as.numeric(data$DATE)), "%d%m%Y")
```

You may have to transform the initial `data$DATE`, depending on what you are strarting from

Comment: Thanks GGamba. This was m original idea. Will give it a go

Comment: I should note that atm the data is saved as an integer

Comment: Even better: just use `as.Date(sprintf('%08d', data$DATE), "%d%m%Y")`